# recommendations for a free image gallery

Tags: image-gallery

I am looking for recommendations for a free image gallery, compatible with ASP.NET and which can load the images reading the location from an xml file.

something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gallery>
   <image id="bk101">
      <name>image1.png</name>
      <title>this is a sample image 1 </title>
   </image>
   <image id="bk102">
      <name>image2.png</name>
      <title>this is a sample image 2 </title>
   </image>
</gallery>
```

Comment: This appears to be a question about adding a webapp to your website. As such, it's off-topic for this site. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com will probably be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Simple Viewer](http://www.simpleviewer.net/simpleviewer/)? I tried it a while back and found it easy to set up with XML files. It's flash based, but you didn't put restrictions on how the gallery was implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, while I am not sure about the asp compatibility, etc, the easier road could be installing something that does quite of the work for you. Some pair of good solutions could be http://bitnami.org/stack/coppermine and http://bitnami.org/stack/gallery